# SoapClient not found - but soap exists

Tags: php, soap, centos, soap-client

I have untypical problem with initialize SoapClient. I am running my VPS on: **CentOS release 6.6 (Final)** - 64 bit

I've installed PHP:

```
[root@hostname tmp]# php --version
PHP 5.4.42 (cli) (built: Jun 10 2015 14:19:12) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group 
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

And php-soap:

```
[root@hostname tmp]# yum install php-soap
Package php-soap-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 is already installed.
```

Commend: php -m displays:

```
[root@hostname tmp]# php -m
[PHP Modules]
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
gmp
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mhash
mysql
mysqli
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
phalcon
Phar
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
xml
zip
zlib
```

Moreover I've runned phpinfo()

[image]

Everything works fine when I use for example: (as test.php)

```
<?php

$client = new SoapClient();

var_dump($client);
```

it recives:

```
[root@hostname tmp]# vim test.php 
[root@hostname tmp]# /usr/bin/php test.php 
PHP Fatal error:  SoapClient::SoapClient(): Invalid parameters in /var/www/app/library/Soap/test.php on line 3
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SoapClient::SoapClient(): Invalid parameters in /var/www/app/library/Soap/test.php:3
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/app/library/Soap/test.php(3): SoapClient->SoapClient()
#1 {main}
thrown in /var/www/app/library/Soap/test.php on line 3

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SoapClient::SoapClient(): Invalid parameters in /var/www/app/library/Soap/test.php:3
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/app/library/Soap/test.php(3): SoapClient->SoapClient()
#1 {main}
thrown in /var/www/app/library/Soap/test.php on line 3
```

So it works. But when I try too open view: localhost/test.php

```
Fatal error: Class 'Vokuro\Soap\SoapClient' not found in
```

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have parameters in SoapClient();

Try use WSDL or null and location/uri
more info in PHP manual:
http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php

Comment: Are you sure "PHP Fatal error:  SoapClient::SoapClient(): Invalid parameters "

Comment: Dude, this option works as you can see. Php is able to find SoapClient class. The problem is when i am trying to run it on httpd as you can see.

Comment: Probably you have problem with namespace?

Comment: So how i should configure namespaces to SoapClient with is included with soap.so?

Answer (score 0):

According to error message I do believe that you are trying to create SoapClient object from a namespace which does not exists.

If the code is just creating and dumping class instance I would definetely check HTTP server/php.ini/php-fpm  configs.

Are you also sure you do not include files from this framework in your code:
https://github.com/phalcon/vokuro

Maybe clearing your WWWRoot directory would help ?